# Getting a USB into 3.5 floppy drive

Tags: usb, adapter, floppy-drive

I'm dealing with a 3.5 inch floppy drive and I'm curious if there's any way to get a USB drive's data directly into the place where the floppy drive would usually be inserted. Is there such a device?

Comment: The floppy is a magnetic disc which is read out by an electromechanical device. So it makes economical to use only the discs and read them out by the drive. Flash is only the electronics itself, you can not separate the reader and the media (more clearly, you could if you would really want it, that would be little gain for big effort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a device which allows a 3.5" floppy drive to read off of Flash memory, simply because the drive itself works through the traditional mechanical means of its media.   Such a device would be similar to a car tape-deck adapter for a CD player, and would be prone to failure anyway.

There are many, many devices like [this one](https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/aclk?sa=L&ai=DChcSEwjwke7i0fTeAhVQA4YKHT59DDwYABABGgJ2dQ&ohost=www.google.com&cid=CAASEuRo6MTqlzvJEgRLylb91FlagQ&sig=AOD64_3rSLTPOgDOhFJ4U2zvNEO5j5bIyw&ctype=5&q=&ved=0ahUKEwjryuji0fTeAhXDjVkKHaqIDIMQ9aACCDU&adurl=) which will allow you to use USB disks with a 3.5" *bay*, however.   They require connection to the USB headers on your motherboard or an expansion card purchased separately.