# USB wired 3.5" Floppy reader for Windows 10

Tags: usb, floppy-drive

I came across some ancient floppies (3.5").  Most are games, but there are some source code ones from very old projects.  I would like to recover them.

Is there a USB wired 3.5: floppy reader?  Cheapish around $100.

Note [this](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10152/getting-a-usb-into-3-5-floppy-drive) is not a duplicate.

Comment: what research have you done? There are so many resources for that type of product, a single simple search will provide you with appropriate results. Prices will range from as low as US$15.00 upward.

Comment: I had not found any at the time of posting, but I did find one later, and have ordered it.